# The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I get this error: The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.
Previous: []
Incoming: [iCWh9p5f36aKGfwzjbplzXtLvFC2]

To prevent it, I first check if **userUID not equal to []** and only then I output useEffect, but I still get the same error

```
 if(auth.currentUser != null){
    
    let userUID = (auth.currentUser.uid)
    
        if(userUID.length > 0){
          console.log(userUID.length)
          
          
          useEffect(() => {
         
                  const q = query(collection(db, "customers", userUID, "subscriptions"));
            
                  onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
                      querySnapshot.forEach(async (subscription) => {
                            setSubscription({
                                role: subscription.data().role,
                                current_period_start:
                          subscription.data().current_period_start.seconds,
                        current_period_end: subscription.data().current_period_end.seconds,
                      });
                    });
                  });
                }, [userUID]) //if I'll put logic inside then this userUID will crash the site because it is equal to null first few secs
          
        }
    }
```

If I need to put if statement inside useEffect => is it possible to export "let" from an if statement?

Something like this:

```
 if(auth.currentUser != null){
    
    let userUID = (auth.currentUser.uid);
    
    export default userUID;
}

useEffect(() => {
                  const q = query(collection(db, "customers", userUID, "subscriptions"))
                  ...
}, [userUID]);
```

Comment: Hooks should not be rendered conditionally. Please see [this](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects)

Comment: Move all of your user logic into the useEffect.

Comment: @Nikki9696 If I'll put "if" inside useEffect ->  auth.currentUser.uid(whıch ıs equal to userUID) which stays after useEffect(      useEffect(() => {...}, [userUID])    )
  will be null because it takes a few seconds to load and the site crashes

Comment: @Nikki9696  Do you happen to know if you can export the "let" from the if statement?
That would solve my problem

Something like this:

*I edited and showed it in the main post*

Comment: Where does `auth` come from? That's your actual dependency. I'd try to write up an example but I'm more a Typescript person and I just know I'd muck up the plain JS  trying to declare the state =)

Comment: Or, as Rico suggested, you can move most of this into the useEffect itself, depending on that `auth` object